How can a compiler perform whole code optimizations if most code are in the form of static libraries?
It's basically the title, but here is some context:
Recently I've been trying to link a C library to a D main in WASM, and successfully produced "hello" to browser console (yay).
This required me to compile my hello_lib.c and hello_world.d to a .o file using a D compiler (ldc), then .o to .wasm with emscripten.
I had some problems at the linking stage, which is the reason I had to use this whole toolchain. If I had used only ldc, it would complain about undefined 'printf' from stdio. (This is not my question, it works normally if you compile for native, just not for WASM. It is solved already.)
The thing is, if up to point where ldc generates a .o file it still doesn't know about 'printf' in stdio, how can it produce whole code optimizations ever? (If you use "-c" flag, ldc produces said .o files and does not complain about 'printf'.)
I always write my code in many libs, just to keep things organized, and I know this won't be a performance hog or anything like that, still, it seems like missed opportunity for the compiler.
Shouldn't it "glue" the code in a huge file first, then make optimizations after that? I though that was what static libraries where all about.

Update: Question is not clear enough
I can choose to compile two sources files into two separate .o files to link them in a separate compiler. Or can I just feed the compiler two source files and let it do it's thing till it generates an executable.
In the first example, would one be missing optimization opportunities in a general use-case? Like a class of "whole program optimizations" outside of "link-time optimizations".

"how can it produce whole code optimizations ever": In traditional compilation models it can't. That's why link-time optimization (LTO) compilation models were developed. This requires compilation of all library code that should be optimized across with this model enabled.

But considering standard library functions like printf specifically, the compiler can perform some optimizations across it, because it knows the semantics of the function from its specification, rather than its implementation. For example a common optimization is to replace printf("%s", x) with puts(x).

Also, the separation boundary in traditional compilation and linking isn't static libraries, but individual translation units, i.e. individual .c/.o files. There is no optimization across multiple of them either, even in the same static library.

Thank you. I'm looking for those references, mainly link time optimization. I'm assuming this is an optional flag for compilers that have support for it. Given your third comment, and Wikipedia, I also think that LTO are just a separate set of optimizations that takes the whole code into account during link-time. Is that correct?
I think the compiler makes multiple passes too, before and after linking, but now I'm just handwaving. I feel the compiler might be missing some optimizations in my "unique" use-case.

Also, for anyone reading, I'm an inexperienced programmer. This might be totally normal and I don't know it yet, but the question seems relevant and more knowledge never hurt anyone before. (actually it did but whtvr).

Static libraries are essentially just a bunch of .o files packaged together. To use whole program optimization you have to specify that when building the contents of the libraries. The linker will then select the parts used by the program (creating the "huge file"), and then let the compiler have a second go at that code.

I realize now "whole program optimization" is a technical term too, and closely related to what I want to know. That's good news, seems a small enough topic I might be able to access the drawbacks of not using WPO by myself. I wouldn't mind a overview tho if am lucky ;) Hopefully, it and LTO are the only things relevant to my question. Thank you.

Compiler optimizations are done on the "translation unit" level. That is, on the specific .c file and all headers it includes. Functions present which may be called externally, or external functions called from the current translation unit are obstacles for the optimizer, since it cannot make as many assumptions about the code then. Whereas link-time optimization is mainly about removing functions that aren't called anywhere in the program, so it is a program size optimization, not execution speed optimization.

@Lundin "Whereas link-time optimization is mainly about removing functions that aren't called anywhere in the program, so it is a program size optimization, not execution speed optimization.": That's for linker optimizations in the traditional compilation/linking model. With LTO as in the new compilation model compilers will perform optimization passes as usual across translation units and can e.g. inline function calls across translation unit boundaries.

@MatheusdeMoraesPeixoto Yes to everything you said. For example GCC and Clang implement LTO (differently) with the -flto flag that should be given during compilation and linking. There also needs to be support in the linker, but that should work out-of-the-box on up-to-date installations. However, it won't out-of-the-box optimize into the C standard library calls, because the library on a normal system hasn't been compiled with -flto. And often times libraries are not designed to work with LTO enabled for various reasons. So naively rebuilding it with LTO may cause all kinds of problems.

Thank you all for the kind answers, they really helped :) I had a fundamental misunderstanding here. I was generating two .o files (which were actually .bc, bitcode from LLVM, I forgot)  to feed emscripten, one for each source. But, if I compile native, the output is a .exe and a single .o (from main), meaning the compiler did put everything together all along. The two .bc files were generated because the compiler stopped before linking. Not that it would matter anyway, given the answer from Eric Postpischil bellow. (If I understood it).


Recently I've been trying to link a C library to a D main in WASM, and successfully produced "hello" to browser console (yay)… If I had used only ldc, it would complain about undefined 'printf' from stdio.

You should have shown the source for the “D main” routine so this could be definitively diagnosed. However, what little you have provided is consistent with the fact that a compiler may take standard library functions as known entities with known behaviors. When this code:
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello, world.\n");
}

is compiled with Apple Clang 15.0.0 for ARM64, the body of the main routine calls puts, not printf:
    adrp    x0, l_str@PAGE
    add x0, x0, l_str@PAGEOFF
    bl  _puts

Thus, the resulting object module will link with a library that contains puts but does not contain printf. This is merely a compile-time optimization, not a link-time optimization.
As for your title question, “How can a compiler perform whole code optimizations if most code are in the form of static libraries?”, link-time optimization can range from very little to, in theory, everything:

In its most rudimentary form, a linker optimizes merely by taking from a static library only those object modules that provide a definition of one or more symbols referenced by previous parts of a program. (“Previous” in the order the linker is working on things.)
Object modules and the rules for them may be designed so that the linker can take only parts of object modules, such as splitting text (instruction) sections at function boundaries and taking only the functions that are used by previous parts of a program.
Object modules may contain additional information besides just traditional object code. GCC can include information about its internal representation of the program in an object module. Thus, the information necessary to do optimization and generate new object code is present in the object module.
At that point, it is just a matter of choice about what information to put into the object module. Theoretically, the entire source code could be stored in the object module. The goal of compiling would be to do as much preparation, analysis, and error reporting as possible while leaving the actual optimization and code generation to the linker.


Thank you. If I understood, it does not matter then If I feed two sources, or two .o files for linking. This is one thing the compiler will figure out, it's mostly an implementation issue. At least for modern ones. Is that correct?

As for the source, I was hesitant to add it just because there are some Dlang details that would distract from the question, but I might later. I get now it might better inform the reader about how I would lose some of these optimizations depending on what is there.

@MatheusdeMoraesPeixoto: The main command for GCC and Clang is “smart”; it will examine the extension of file names listed on the command line and decide whether to compile it or use it for linking based on whether the extension indicates a source file or an object file. This is not the same thing as link-time optimization.

I understand, but I can choose to compile two sources files into two separate .o files to, then, link them in a separate compiler. Or can I just feed the compiler two source files and let it do it's thing till it generates an executable. In both cases, I think I won't miss any optimization opportunities in a general use case. That's what I don't know. My question was not clear, I will update the question body.
